# MYSQL query using a session user in JAVA

Tags: java, mysql, sql, eclipse, jdbc

I'm trying to run this this query from Eclipse:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        String name = session.getAttribute("user").toString();
        String query = "SELECT DISTINCT t.text, t.user, t.date"
                + " FROM users u, tweets t, follows f" 
                + " Where t.parent is null"
                + " AND u.id ="+name
                + " AND ( f.follower = u.id"
                + " AND f.followed = t.user"
                + " OR t.user = u.id)"
                + " ORDER BY t.date DESC;";
```

But I get the following error:

```
Sesion(user):Takeshi
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'Takeshi' in 'where clause'
```

I can imagine the error is because I am doing wrong the comparison between u.id and name, but how should I do it? with some special character? Thanks in advance.

Comment: your concatenation is wrong; try this `+ " AND u.id = '" + name + "'"`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Could you please use following snippet:

```
String name = session.getAttribute("user").toString();
name = name.replace("\'", "''"); 

String query =   " SELECT DISTINCT t.text, t.user, t.date"
                + " FROM users u, tweets t, follows f" 
                + " Where t.parent is null"
                + " AND u.id = '"+name+"'"
                + " AND ( f.follower = u.id"
                + " AND f.followed = t.user"
                + " OR t.user = u.id)"
                + " ORDER BY t.date DESC";
```

Comment: ( cc: @Gera ) ... and what happens when `name = "O'Neill"` ...?

Comment: @GordThompson Could you please have a look at my edited answer?